# I have issue with sending emails using nodemailer

Tags: javascript, html, css, nodemailer

When I am trying to send an email through my contact form I am getting an error that says
'address you are using is not belonging to this platform' <- I am using e-mail from another platform to send message. The O2.pl platform I use only to receive the message but it seems like every person who wants to send an e-mail has to send from account registered in o2.pl platform.
Here is my code

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'poczta.o2.pl',
  port: 587,  
  secure: false,
  auth: {
    user: 'email@o2.pl',
    pass: 'password'
  }
})
const mailOptions = {
  from: req.body.email,
  to: 'email@o2.pl',
  subject: `message from ${req.body.email}: ${req.body.subject}`,
    text: req.body.message
  }
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if(error){
      console.log(error);
      res.send('error');
    }
    else{
      console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
      res.send('success')
    }
  })
})
```

here is another code

```
const contactForm = document.querySelector('.contactFormm');

let email = document.getElementById('email');
let name = document.getElementById('name');
let subject = document.getElementById('subject');
let message = document.getElementById('message');

contactForm.addEventListener('submit', (e)=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  let formData = {
    email: email.value,
    name: name.value,
    subject: subject.value,
    message: message.value
  }
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', '/');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
  xhr.onload = function(){
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
    if(xhr.responseText =='success'){
      alert('Email sent');
      email.value = '';
      name.value = '';
      subject.value = '';
      message.value = '';
    }
    else{
      alert('Something went wrong!')
    }
  }
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify(formData))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your snippet looks good. Have you tried using gmail to test in order to ascertain if there is an issue with poczta?

Comment: Hi, Yes, I tried with gmail and it worked fine but doesn't work with this one. When I try to us it, and sent e-mail from the form, it says 'this e-mail is not registered with poczta' but I set poczta to receive e-mails and not user to send e-mails with e-mail registered with this server. I don't know what's wrong. Is it possible that there is a problem with their server and they set their portal to work their way?